# vba macro looping through files but failing to loop through worksheets

Tags: vba, file, loops, worksheet

I've created a vba macro with the intention of:
1) Opening each file in a folder one by one
2) Loop through each worksheet, unprotect each sheet see if the top row is blank (and delete it if it is) and delete a problematic column.
3) Save the file as an xlsx.

So far I've managed to get it to loop through every file but fail to loop through the worksheets. I was previously able to get it to make changes to the last active worksheet in each workbook but now it seems to skip every worksheet.

Any idea why?

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()

    FolderName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Source Data\"
    If Right(FolderName, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then FolderName = FolderName & Application.PathSeparator
    Fname = Dir(FolderName & "*.xls*")

    'loop through the files
    Do While Len(Fname)

        With Workbooks.Open(FolderName & Fname)
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim filename As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet


Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False

'Unshare Workbook
If ActiveWorkbook.MultiUserEditing Then
    ActiveWorkbook.ExclusiveAccess
End If

'Unprotect Workbook
ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect "pa55word"


For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

'Unprotect Worksheet
ws.Unprotect "pa55word"

'Unhide Columns and Rows
            ws.Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            ws.Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False


 'Delete Blank top Row
 Set MR = ws.Range("A1:C1")
 For Each cell In MR
 If cell.Value = "" Then cell.EntireRow.Delete
 Next

  'Delete annoying Column
 Set MR = ws.Range("A1:BZ1")
 For Each cell In MR
 If cell.Value = "a2a" Then cell.EntireColumn.Delete
 Next

 'Remove Filter

 If ws.AutoFilterMode Then
 ws.ShowAllData
 ws.AutoFilterMode = False
 End If

 Next ws


ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Cleansed Data\" & Replace(Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".xlsx", ""), ".xls", "") & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51
ActiveWorkbook.Close

        End With

        ' go to the next file in the folder
        Fname = Dir

    Loop



End Sub
```

Comment: Just a guess,  but change every `ActiveSheet` to `ws`. You never setted ws as the active worksheet, so it only takes effect in the last active

Comment: It would be more helpful to _not_ post a lengthy set of code that is functioning _properly_, and removing as much as possible while still producing the problem, so that focus can be put on the _actual_ problem.,   Please read: [mcve] plus https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and [ask].

Comment: ...on the other hand, there are members like @Vityata and Magnetron, who have X-Ray VBA Glasses.  (Read the links I posted anyway, to help with your next question.)  :-)

Comment: @ashleedawg - that made me smile, thanks! :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Magnetron but unfortunately that didn't work.

Comment: indenting the code properly might help. Also, have you stepped through the code checking exected values and flow against at actual?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ActiveSheet` to unprotect in the loop.

Change it to this one:

```
 For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                'Unprotect Worksheet
                ws.Unprotect "pa55word" 'instead of ActiveSheet.Unprotect ~
```

Otherwise it stays protected and you cannot do the changes. In general, avoid working with `ActiceCell`, `ActiveSheet` and etc - [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Furthermore, set the `MR` range like this:

```
'Delete Blank top Row
Set MR = ws.Range("A1:C1")
For Each cell In MR
    If cell.Value = "" Then cell.EntireRow.Delete
Next

'Delete annoying Column
Set MR = ws.Range("A1:BZ1")
For Each cell In MR
    If cell.Value = "2a2" Then cell.EntireColumn.Delete
Next
```

You have to refer to the `ws` parent, when you are setting the range. Otherwise it takes the `ActiveSheet`.

---

And here as well:

```
 If ws.AutoFilterMode Then
     ws.ShowAllData
     ws.AutoFilterMode = False
 End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.unfortunately this didn't work, it still failed to apply changes to any sheets besides the last active one. I also tried Magnetron's suggestion and that didn't fix it.

Comment: when I made the change that you suggested it simply skipped all the worksheets.

Comment: @Anonymous - look through all your code, there are some non-defined ranges and cells. And see the edit once again.

Comment: I actually did make the change to all ranges in my script, sorry I should have mentioned that in my previous comment. I've updated the code in my original post to reflect this.

Comment: it doesn't work, it doesn't even apply changes to the last active worksheet when I made the changes to the ranges and cells.

Comment: @Anonymous - I see. This is because of the `ThisWorkbook` part. Try to set the `Workbook` as a variable. And not to refer to the `ThisWorkbook`, `ActiveWorksheet` and etc.

Comment: I tried "Workbook" and it errored with "run-time error '4' Object required" and when I debugged the code it errored on "for each ws in Workbook.Worksheets". I also tried ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets and wb.worksheets which seems to open a file and have it stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: @Anonymous - you have to set the a variable as  a `Workbook`. Take a look at the articles here, they are all good - https://www.google.com/search?q=loop+through+workbooks+vba

Answer (score 0):

It is always Excel.Object, Workbook.Object, Worksheet.Object, and Range.Object; 4 objects total.  Please take a look at this link.

http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Objects.html

Also, see this link.

http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/loop-through-books-sheets.html

So, now with your new education, you are ready to do the actual work.

```
Sub Example()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String, Fnum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim ErrorYes As Boolean

    'Fill in the path\folder where the files are
    MyPath = "C:\Users\Ron\test"

    'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    'If there are no Excel files in the folder exit the sub
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
    Fnum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        Fnum = Fnum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
        MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
    If Fnum > 0 Then
        For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(Fnum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then


                'Change cell value(s) in one worksheet in mybook
                On Error Resume Next
                With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                    If .ProtectContents = False Then
                        .Range("A1").Value = "My New Header"
                    Else
                        ErrorYes = True
                    End If
                End With


                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    ErrorYes = True
                    Err.Clear
                    'Close mybook without saving
                    mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                Else
                    'Save and close mybook
                    mybook.Close savechanges:=True
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0
            Else
                'Not possible to open the workbook
                ErrorYes = True
            End If

        Next Fnum
    End If

    If ErrorYes = True Then
        MsgBox "There are problems in one or more files, possible problem:" _
             & vbNewLine & "protected workbook/sheet or a sheet/range that not exist"
    End If

    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub
```

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win010.htm